# Isonormal Gaussian process associated with a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, gaussian, malliavin-calculus

We consider the isonormal Gaussian process $W=\{W(h),h\in H\}$  indexed by a separable Hilbert space $H$, defined on a complete probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F,P)$ where $\mathcal F:=\sigma(W)$, i.e. $W(h)$ is a centered Gaussian random variable  and the covariance structure is defined by 
$$E(W(h)W(g))=\langle h,g\rangle_H.$$

For example $W$ is the Wiener-Ito integral, $H$ is (a deterministic) $L^2([0,T])$ space and $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ is the Wiener probability space.

Another example could be for instance $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R),\nu)$ where $\nu$ is the standard Gaussian measure, $H=\mathbb R$, and $W(h)(x)=h\cdot x, \forall h\in H$.

---

In this two examples we can see that the probability space and the associated Hilbert space are of the "same type"; I mean, in the first example $\Omega$ and $H$ and function spaces, in the second one $\Omega$ and $H$ are one dimensional spaces (or finite dimensional in general).

**I've been wondering for quite some time (and it may perfectly be a non-sense question) if for instance we can have $H$ to be an $L^2$ space and $\Omega$ a finite dimensional space?**

**More generally, is there some relation that we must satisfy between the space $\Omega$ and the space $H$?**
(being both function spaces or finite dimensional, etc)

Thanks in advance and I apologice if this is something trivial.

Comment: The notion of being a function space isn't captured by the Hilbert structure of $H$ and the notion of being a finite dimensional vector space isn't captured by the measure space structure of $\Omega$. This means you can just take one of your examples above as well as any other Hilbert space $G$ such that there is an isomorphism $H \to G$ and any other measure space $\Omega'$ such that there is an isomorphism of measure spaces from $\Omega \to \Omega'$ and then get a white noise indexed by $G$ with probability space $\Omega'$ using these isomorphisms.

Comment: I knew you could help me @RhysSteele! Thank you so much

Comment: @RhysSteele However if I take isomorphisms then they will end up having the same dimensions right? So for instance I cannot have a process indexed by an $L^2$ space defined on the measure space $\mathbb R$ ,or I am missing something?

Comment: Bear with me I'm an economist playing to be a mathematician :)

Comment: I guess there are non-trivial constraints on what kind of pairs you can put together sure. For example, if $H = L^2$ then by considering $W(e_i)$ for $e_i$ in an orthonormal basis, you see that $\Omega$ must support a family of independent standard Gaussians (I'd guess this isn't true of $\mathbb{R}$ with the gaussian measure but I don't have a proof in mind so that's really no more than a wild guess). Is there a reason you want to think about this though? Normally one doesn't pay so much attention to the precise probability space because it won't end up mattering at all